# google compute engine VM instance : my root password?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm using google cloud platform compute engine.
I created a VM instance (OS : Ubuntu 16.04)
I want to change some system config. However system requires me to enter password.

[image]

I haven't got password. I don't know my password.

What is my password?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default there is *no* root password on GCE instances. You have several options:

1. As [all users are added to sudoers](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/user-accounts/#root_access), you can run the command as root with: `sudo invoke-rc.d procps start`
2. You can log in as root with `sudo -i`
3. You can set a root password by running `sudo passwd`

Comment: Use `sudo -i`. It is great.

Answer (score 5):

GCE don't set any clear-text password for any user, it only sets ssh keys 
You can  ssh into instance directly from web console
You can use all root privileges by using `sudo [COMMAND --ARG1..]`
To set root password ssh into instance
Type : `sudo passwd root` (for linux machines)
It will ask for new password but whatever password you are typing won't show,  It's hidden, just press enter after done typing
Also if you are trying to ssh into instance as root, you will need to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd.config` and change Permit root login and Password Authentication to yes

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

By default, there's no root password on your VM instance. If you want, you can set it manually.

```
sudo -i
sudo passwd
```

Comment: Why would you need `sudo` on the second command; or, conversely, why would you use `sudo -i` to start an interactive session if you only want to run one command?